# Celery task doesn't save model

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I have post_save signal, that holds `task.delay()`. Task contains some code, that ends with saving model. I handled recursion and I know, that task is succeeded. The problem is, in my task if I change one field in model, in logs of task I see correct info, but when I go to db or in Django admin, field contains info like "before celery task". So the question is, what's wrong? If need, can provide code. Code throws no exceptions.

Thanks in advance.

```
def recode(self, repetitions, newPath, meditationId):
from meditations.models import Meditation
for i in range(repetitions - 1):
    command = 'ffmpeg -i {}{}.m4a -i {}.m4a -filter_complex "acrossfade=duration=5:curve1=exp:curve2=exp" -y {}{}.m4a'.format(newPath, i, newPath, newPath, i + 1)
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    os.remove('{}{}.m4a'.format(newPath, i))
command = 'ffmpeg -i {}{}.m4a -movflags +faststart -ss 0 -to 7200 -y {}{}.m4a '.format(newPath, repetitions - 1,
                                                                                       newPath, repetitions)
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

newPath = newPath + str(repetitions) + '.m4a'
meditation = Meditation.objects.get(id=meditationId)
meditation.audio = File(open(newPath, 'rb'))
meditation.save()

return newPath, meditation.id, meditation.audio.name
```

Here is task code. I don't think u need part with ffmpeg its about turning .mp3 to .m4a Field that changes is audio. Its a FileField of Meditation model. Task response is always like

> ('AudioTracks/mystery-whistle-melody_101bpm_C_minor_bqXcdHB3.m4a', 2,
> 'AudioTracks/AudioTracks/mystery-whistle-melody_101bpm_C_minor_bqXcdHB3.m4a')

Also, strange detail that Django saves audio properly, I mean it moves it to `upload_to` directory as it do with any file given to FileField or ImageField.

Comment: Please post the code of the task.

Comment: Here you go. Post_save holds no special lines, just some little manipulations

Comment: Does the code work outside the task? The issue could also be that the celery worker does not have access to that file system.

Comment: the code outside the task works well. To be honest, at first I did it as a single method, but the circumstances are such that I need to do convert async with celery.

Comment: are you saving a binary file to the database?

Comment: Didn't understand a question. U see meditation.save(), files correctly lays in folders. Its seem to be problem of docker because I tried even a raw command that will update straightly db, but it still don't work

Answer (score 0):

This issue can't be solved like this because the celery worker is in a different docker container (with a different file system) and it can not access the file. If you add some logging to the celery task, you would get the info that the file was not successfully accessed (and therefore the model instance never saved).

You will need to find some other way to access the file in the celery worker. One example would be an AWS S3 bucket or some other prominent media store.

Comment: U are wrong, celery has access, because ffmpeg does the trick and as result a have 2 hour m4a file. I did it with shared  volume. Anyway, i did convertion to m4a in django container and in celery just replace file with modified one.

Comment: Check your env variables (SQL_ENGINE, CELERY_BROKER, etc), they must be the same in django and celery containers.